# How to detect if users stop typing in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an EditText field in my layout. I want to perform an action when the user stops typing in that edittext field. I have implemented TextWatcher and use its functions

```
@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }


@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence text, int start, int lengthBefore, int lengthAfter) { } 

@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

    }
```

The function `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged` get called just after typing any character, but I want to perform action after the user has finished typing in that edittext field, just like facebook does on it's "Check In" page.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is how I did and works for me!

```
long delay = 1000; // 1 seconds after user stops typing
long last_text_edit = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable input_finish_checker = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > (last_text_edit + delay - 500)) {
            // TODO: do what you need here
            // ............
            // ............
            DoStuff();
        }
    }
};

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStopId);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count,
    int after){
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged ( final CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count){
        //You need to remove this to run only once
        handler.removeCallbacks(input_finish_checker);

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged ( final Editable s){
        //avoid triggering event when text is empty
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            last_text_edit = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(input_finish_checker, delay);
        } else {

        }
    }
}

);
```

Comment: what is the logic behind this (last_text_edit + delay - 500).Why do we need the 500?

Comment: What i have to do if i want to pass  `EditText` string to `DoStuff()` method. which is in `input_finish_checker` method.

Answer (score 24):

There is a very simple and easy way of doing this using `RxBindings` for Android,

Get the library if you haven't already,

```
compile 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0'
```

Add and modify this snippet to your needs,

```
RxTextView.textChanges(mEditText)
            .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(textChanged -> {
                Log.d("TAG", "Stopped typing!");
            });
```

*What is Debounce Operator?* - [Learn more about it here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html)

In our context, debounce will only notify you of the text change inside the `EditText` after a certain time has passed from the last text change that occurred inside the `EditText`.

Here I am waiting for **3 seconds** until the last text change happened to conclude that the user has stopped typing. You can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks, much better than textWatcher for sending server requests after text change.

Answer (score 22):

If you use Kotlin, use this extension function:

```
fun TextView.afterTextChangedDelayed(afterTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        var timer: CountDownTimer? = null

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {}

        override fun afterTextChanged(editable: Editable?) {
            timer?.cancel()
            timer = object : CountDownTimer(1000, 1500) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {}
                override fun onFinish() { 
                    afterTextChanged.invoke(editable.toString()) 
                }
            }.start()
        }
    })
}
```

Use example:

```
editTextPassword.afterTextChangedDelayed {
    registerViewModel.addUserPassword(it)
}
```

Comment: It's doesn't work at all. afterTextChangedDelayed() get called several times when implemented.

Comment: Of course, it is called every time you stop typing after X time

Comment: works beautifully, thanks @EmmanuelGuther

Answer (score 10):

You could use a focus change listener. If the edittext has focus then assume user still editing otherwise they have stopped and you can perform your action:

```
EditText et = new EditText(mContext);
et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            //user has focused
        Toast.makeText(this, "Typing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //focus has stopped when user move to next edit text 
           //perform your desired action
        Toast.makeText(this, "Typing Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
});
```

`afterTextChanged` is used to detect when the user stops typing

```
et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        public void onTextChanged(...) {}

        public void beforeTextChanged(...) {}

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable e) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Typing Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

It is a little different kind of approach. But you can do something like this

I am assuming that after a user started typing in the edittext,  and he didn't typed for a particular time period than it can be considered that he stopped typing.

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        boolean isTyping = false;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        private Timer timer = new Timer();
        private final long DELAY = 5000; // milliseconds

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            Log.d("", "");
            if(!isTyping) {
                Log.d(TAG, "started typing");
                // Send notification for start typing event
                isTyping = true;
            }
            timer.cancel();
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.schedule(
                    new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            isTyping = false;
                            Log.d(TAG, "stopped typing");
                            //send notification for stopped typing event
                        }
                    },
                    DELAY
            );
        }
    });
```

Basically what you are doing here is, that whenever a user starts typing, if there is a time gap of 5000 milliseconds in changing the text inside the edittext, you consider as the user has stopped typing. Of course you can change the time to whatever you want

Comment: I personally don't like this approach, what if the user is talking with a friend whilst entering text and stops typing? you could fix this by increasing the time but then the desired effect will be lost.

Comment: but than there is no better way to conclude whether he is typing or not.

Comment: there is, if they have took focus away from edit text then they cannot possibly be typing,

Comment: what if the user is talking with a friend whilst entering text and and keeps the phone aside without the focus being removed from the edittext. That way he is typing because of focus but in reality he is not.

Comment: agreed, but that is far less likely than someone stopping for 5seconds whilst talking. if someone puts there phone down for that long the effect will be lost anyway. plus OP can restart the listener when focused again anyway

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal you can solve that by using onFocusChangeListener. When the EditText has focus you can do something and when the focus is lost you can do something else :)

Comment: working very well.. you can just change the time from 5000 seconds to whatever suits you...

Comment: FocusChangeListener is a bad approach. Who takes the focus away after typing? I had the focus solution implemented ona product and nobody clicked to remove focus. We had to implement the timer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this extension function to get the text typed by user after stop writing.

Example:

```
myEditText.doAfterTextChanged{ text ->
// Do your work here
}
```

The default time is set to 500 ms, so the text change callback will be invoked after 500 ms from the moment user stop writing. You can change the default time as param to the function.

Example:

```
myEditText.doAfterTextChanged(delay = 1000){ text ->
// Do your work here
}
```

So the listener will be invoked exactly after 1 second after user stop writing.

Gist Link: https://gist.github.com/rommansabbir/c56cb28e84bdc499cfd7c63180fb9f95

Answer (score 4):

I used a CountDownTimer to find out if the user stopped typing after a while. I hope to help.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        CountDownTimer timer = null;

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            if (timer != null) {
                timer.cancel();
            }

            timer = new CountDownTimer(1500, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                }

                public void onFinish() {

                    //do what you wish

                }

            }.start();

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

```kotlin
import android.os.Handler
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher

class EndTypingWatcher(
        var delayMillis: Long = DELAY,
        val action: () -> Unit

) : Handler(), TextWatcher {
    companion object {
        private const val DELAY: Long = 1000
    }

    var lastEditTime: Long = 0

    private val finishCheckerRunnable = Runnable {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > lastEditTime + delayMillis - 500) {
            action.invoke()
        }
    }

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
        afterTextChanged()
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        onTextChanged()
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    }

    private fun afterTextChanged() {
        lastEditTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        postDelayed(finishCheckerRunnable, delayMillis)
    }

    private fun onTextChanged() {
        removeCallbacks(finishCheckerRunnable)
    }

}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
private const val DELAY_AFTER_STOP_TYPING = 2000

...

editText.addTextChangedListener(EndTypingWatcher(delayMillis = DELAY_AFTER_STOP_TYPING) {
    //Some end action
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use coroutines instead of timer or handler to implement this like RxTextView you can also observe when user start typing

```
import android.text.Editable
import android.text.TextWatcher
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class TypingListener(private val onTyping: (Boolean) -> Unit) : TextWatcher {

companion object {
    private const val DEBOUNCE_PERIOD = 1000L
}

private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)

private var typingJob: Job? = null

private var isNotTyping = true

override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
    if (isNotTyping){
        onTyping(isNotTyping)
        isNotTyping = false
    }
}

override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) { }

override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    typingJob?.cancel()
    s?.let {
        typingJob = coroutineScope.launch {
            delay(DEBOUNCE_PERIOD)
            onTyping(isNotTyping)
            isNotTyping = true
        }
    }
}
```

> use it with your editext like this as u get typingStatus Boolean to know typing status

```
edit_text.addTextChangedListener(TypingListener{ typingStatus-> })
```