# I have to run a function just once when after user stops typing but my function runs multiple times

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have to run a function just once when after the user stops typing but my function runs multiple times.I have detected when a user stops typing but can't execute my function just once.

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, final int i, final   
    int i1, final int i2) {   
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    //Run after user stops typing
    TimerTask tt = new TimerTask() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Date myRunTime = new Date();
        if ((lastTypeTime.getTime() + 1000) <= myRunTime.getTime()) {
          Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
          h.post(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            Log.i("t_type", "Type Finish");
            //Issue : This is printed multiple time.
          }
        });
      } else {
        Log.i("t_cancel", "cancel");//cancel
      }
    }
  };
  timer.schedule(tt, 2000);//two second delay after user stops typing
}
```

Comment: How do you know when user stop typing can you show your code.

Comment: It is because you used timerTask try different AlarmManager. use http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html

Comment: It's run every 2 second

Comment: onTextChanged helps me to run timer task after typing is stop

Comment: ya run() function runs multiple times I dont know why ??

Comment: I thing your onTextChanged  call multiple time so because of it run call multiple time

Comment: @jiteshmohite ya thats the reason. Do you have any idea how can this be solved ?

Comment: try to type only one char and see the logs these should call only ones. plz tell me

Comment: ya it call only ones.

Comment: thats the problem with onTextChanged . for every char typing onTextChanged will be called so you have to use bad checks in your program

Comment: refere these link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35224459/how-to-detect-if-users-stop-typing-in-edittext-android

Comment: @jiteshmohite thanks now i think problem is solved i have posted my answer down below.

Comment: welcome brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the issue in this way. thanks @jitesh mohite

```
  @Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    Log.i("t_text", editable.toString());
    if (!isTyping) {
        isTyping = true;
        Log.i("t_type", "Typing");
    }
    timer.cancel();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Handler handler = new 

android.os.Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Log.i("t_type", "Type Finish");
                    Toast.makeText(SearchActivity.this, "Type Finish", 

Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    isTyping = false;
                }
            });
        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did and works for me!

```
long delay = 1000; // 1 seconds after user stops typing
long last_text_edit = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable input_finish_checker = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() > (last_text_edit + delay - 500)) {
            // TODO: do what you need here
            // ............
            // ............
            DoStaff();
        }
    }
};

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextStopId);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s,int start, int count, int after){

    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged ( final CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
        //You need to remove this to run only once
        handler.removeCallbacks(input_finish_checker);

    }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged ( final Editable s){
        //avoid triggering event when text is empty
        if (s.length() > 0) {
            last_text_edit = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(input_finish_checker, delay);
        } else {

        }
    }
  }

);
```