# How to receive final afterTextChanged event, for EditText with spelling suggestion (without turning off)

Tags: android

Currently, I need to capture the final appeared text in `EditText`.

Here's my simple code.

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                Log.i("CHEOK", ">>>" + editable.toString() + "<<<");
                doSomething(editable.toString());
            }

            private void doSomething() {}
        });
    }
}
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"

    android:imeOptions="actionSend" />
```

Here's how it behave.

### When there's no spelling suggestion

[image]

When I press ENTER

[image]

`afterTextChanged` is being triggered **one** time with the following output.

```
>>>123
456<<<
```

### When spelling suggestion is there

[image]

When I press ENTER

[image]

`afterTextChanged` is being triggered **multiple** time with the following output.

```
>>>def<<<
>>><<<
>>>abc
<<<
>>>abc
def<<<
```

I'm not interested the **intermediate text** in between. I'm only interested in final text (which is `abc\ndef`)

How possible can I have something like

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
    if (isFinalText(edittable.toString())) {
        doSomething(editable.toString());
    }
}
```

without turning off spelling suggestion.

### P/S

I don't mind to extends `EditText`, and do some hacking within it. However, I had tried to override `dispatchKeyEvent` and `onKeyPreIme` in `EditText`. Not sure why they are not being called.

### P/S/S

I'm also try `onEditorAction` technique as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/8063533/72437 It won't work for my case as my `EditText` is multi-line.

Comment: i think you can't , moreover for different keyboards you will get different intermediate state. The only way out is to unregister the text watcher in after text change. Set your text and then again register the textwatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a correct solution to solve my faced problem. The key is to use

```
editText.post
```

---

### Solution

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edit_text);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(final Editable editable) {
                final String originalString = editable.toString();

                editText.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        String text = editText.getText().toString();
                        if (text.equals(originalString)) {
                            Log.i("CHEOK", originalString);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The idea is, when the time posted function is executed, `editText.getText()` is returning a complete text (`abc\ndef`)

Adding `if (text.equals(originalString))`, is to ignore 2 intermediate texts in between (`def` and `abc\n`)

Comment: I didn't get this. What you describe in your question is not resolved in this. Please can you explain this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I come to the conclusion :

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (prevString.length() >= s.length()) {
                if (userIsInteracting) {
                    doSomething(s.toString());
                }
            } else {
                doSomething(s.toString());
            }
            prevString = s.toString();
        }
    });
 editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL)
                    userIsInteracting = true;
                Log.d("key event", keyCode + event.toString());
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        userIsInteracting = false;
                    }
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Do try it out, It will work for sure. I tried and working perfectly.
Happy Coding!!!

Comment: This has nothing to do with `Activity`. The `EditText` can be placed in `RecyclerListView`, or in `Fragment`

Comment: Okay no issues , then get callback from your parent Activity whichever control you use in Fragment implement custom method and then 
if(userIsInteracting())
doSomething();

Comment: Or you can make delay to the text change listener go to this
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38524158/3303075

Comment: Unfortunately, android is not providing such events like clicked on suggested word from keyboard.

Comment: Use field variable :
private String prevString = "";

Comment: Edited my Answer pls check
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49443717/3303075